# How to show or hide an element based on ip address

Tags: javascript, ip-address

Let's say I have this div element and I have the IP of 0.0.0.1 and the div is not showing but I go in the site with the IP of 0.0.0.2 and the div shows any idea of how to do this??

Comment: Let's back up and ask _why_ you need to do this, because the only thing that reliably knows the IP address of who it's talking to is the server, which is why make servers send different responses based on IP, if that's the kind of data flow you need. The browser can lie to your JS as much as it wants, and you'll never know because you don't control the user's browser, they do. You control the server.

Comment: right, so why make the client do that, instead of the server? The server will have your "who is an admin" logic, and can send a page response that includes, or does not include, your `admin-stuff.js` file, which will then load for any browser being used by folks on computers with cleared IP addresses. Plus, this way you can make the server record that any _interactions_ from that script will be allowed. Even if someone hacks that script load into their page, your server will still know that "actually, no, you don't get to interact with me for admin-only calls"

Comment: your server (PHP, express, whatever) gets to decide what content people get when they ask for a page. So, your make your server (through page templating, or page render context) include, or not include, something like `<script src="./js/admin.js"></script>` if the requesting computer's IP address is one of the addresses that you've configured as "these should see admin stuff", including people manually editing their DOM in the browser to load that script in anyway. The server can simply respond with a 403 code because their IP is not allowed to ever load that file.

Comment: So on that note: please include some text (and tags, if applicable) that explains which server software, or which hosting, you're using. Because making JS do this is the worst way to try to add this: it would be trivial to make the browser report a false IP and bam, not-allowed-to-see-that-contant users can now see all the content they're not allowed to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go directly to a URL like http://10.10.10.10/, you can get the 'host' part with `document.location.hostname`.

If you use a domain, you cannot find out what ip is associated with the domain.